# Header in subfolder not found

Tags: linux, makefile, g++

my compiler does not found a header in a subfolder included in a cpp file 
`#include "comm\ComPublic.h"`

My master makefile :

```
SUB_POUET=Pouet \
            PouetTech \
            PouetPrivate

all: $(SUB_POUET)

PouetTech:
    @(cd PouetTech && $(MAKE))

Pouet:
    @(cd Pouet && $(MAKE))

PouetPrivate:
    @(cd PouetPrivate && $(MAKE))

.PHONY: clean mrproper $(SUB_POUET)

clean:
    @(cd $(SUB_POUET) && $(MAKE) $@)

mrproper: clean
    @(cd $(SUB_POUET) && $(MAKE) $@)
```

Sub-makefile1 :

```
include ../Definitions.mif

SRC=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ_FILES=$(addprefix $(OBJECTS_DIR)/,$(notdir $(SRC:.cpp=.o)))
INCLUDES=-I../PouetTech -I../../libs/MPSSE -I../../libs/FTDI/$(OS) -I../shared -I../../libs/libmodbus-3.0.6/src
CXXFLAGS+=$(INCLUDES)

all: $(OBJ_FILES)

$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%o: %cpp | objects_dir 
    $(CXX) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS)


objects_dir:
    mkdir -p $(OBJECTS_DIR)

.PHONY: clean mrproper

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

Sub-makefile 2

```
include ../Definitions.mif

SRC=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ_FILES=$(addprefix $(OBJECTS_DIR)/,$(notdir $(SRC:.cpp=.o)))
INCLUDES=-I../PouetTech -I../Pouet -I../shared
CXXFLAGS+=$(INCLUDES)

all: $(OBJ_FILES)

$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%o: %cpp | objects_dir 
    $(CXX) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS)


objects_dir:
    mkdir -p $(OBJECTS_DIR)

.PHONY: clean mrproper

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

Sub-makefile 3 is identical to 2.
And my folder are like this:

```
src
  |_makefile
  |_Pouet
  |   |_makefile
  |_PouetTech
  |   |_makefile
  |_PouetPrivate
  |   |_makefile
  |_shared
      |_comm
        |_ComPublic.h
```

The problem appears during the 3rd makefile (PouetPrivate), but the folder "shared" is included in the makefile.

If I add `-I../shared/comm` to the makefile and change the include to `#include "ComPublic.h"` it works. But I dont want to include manually all folder  in the makefile.

It's probable just a simple mistake, but I dont have much experience in makefile

Furthermore, its working fine when using mingw / msys under windows or Visual Studio

Edit : and I have the same issue with another subfolder of "comm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the include directive in your source is `#include "comm\ComPublic.h"` as you've written, the problem is simply that you're using the Windows path delimeter `\`. Linux (and g++) want `/` and won't recognise the path.

Fortunately, Visual C++ will accept both delimiters so `/` can be used throughtout.